# Does Go correctly marshal float64 to JSON?

Tags: json, go, dart, marshalling, unmarshalling

Using go1.1.2 Win64, I have a Go program that "marshal"'s a struct containing a float64. When the value of the float64 is not a whole number eg. 1234.44, then it gets "marshal"ed as a float (json.Marshal). When however it is a whole number eg. "1234.00" it is marshalled as an integer"1234". When I receive that at the other end (Dart), Dart (30188) treats the whole number as an integer (in map - JSON.decode). Consequently the Dart program aborts when the representation of the float (double) data doesn't contain a decimal point, and I attempt to "extract" it from the map as a double.

This can obviously be solved a number of different ways (eg. convert to integer and then convert back to float), however I wondered if there is another (better) way to handle this situation.

Is there another better way to handle this than to convert float64 to integer?

Answer (score 8):

JSON, just like Javascript, doesn't differ between integers and numbers.

If Dart treats `1234.00` differently from `1234`, then it is making assumptions about the value not supported by the [JSON specification](http://json.org).

While Go does indeed marshal float64 correctly, one way of getting around the problem with Dart's assumption is by implementing the [Marshaler interface](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) on your own type:

```
type Number float64

func (n Number) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // There are probably better ways to do it. It is just an example
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%f", n)), nil
}
```

And then you can use your own `Number` type, instead of `float64`, in the structs that you will Marshal. This way you can make sure that your numbers will always be marshaled with a decimal point.

Working example on [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/PIGW2Y0fiG)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think this should be solved on the Dart end. It appears that an integer cannot be assigned to a double in Dart. This appear to me an anomaly, but I accept that I am wrong at least from a theoretical perspective (cast-up, cast-down, etc.). The solution that I currently have is as follows :   "double dAcctBal  = (mAcctData['D_AcctBal'] as num) /1;" (where mAcctData is the map where "D_AcctBal" can be an integer or a double depending on whether it is a whole number). This solution to me appears a bit of a hack, but if an integer cannot be assigned to a double directly?

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would be best to solve it on the Dart end. I would also happily give you such a solution if I knew, but my experience with Dart is *very* limited. Maybe someone with more knowledge can find a more idiomatic Dart solution.

Comment: JSON doesn't specify the semantics of its number literals, so it's no more correct to use doubles than integers. Dart has two number types. Anything containing a decimal point or an exponential part must be a double, and everything else is parsed as an integer, which in Dart provides more precision than doubles. This preserves as much information from the JSON number as possible. It does require you to manually use .toDouble if you want all the numbers to be doubles.

Comment: @Irn While it is correct to use whatever suits you, int, double, string, etc. to store the information of a JSON number, it would be wrong to presume 1234.0 to be a double because of the decimal point. 1234.0 equals 1234 in both value and type (number). The decimal point carries no information to preserve; such presumptions will cause problems. However, if Dart also parses 1234.0 as `int` (I hope it does), then the int type would simply state that there are no decimals, which would be without any type presumption.

Answer (score 3):

The following appears to be (to me) the solution. The integer method toDouble() also works with "num" (or vice versa). It appears to me that when working with json and monetary values that could be interpreted as either double or int by Dart, that it is necessary to use "as num" and then use the built-in method toDouble().

Example (Go):

```
type cuAcctRow struct {
         .....
    D_AcctBal    float64
         .....
}
    if baJsAcctDet, oOsError = json.Marshal(uAcctRow); oOsError != nil {
```

Example (Dart):

```
Map mAcctData = json.parse(sResponse);

double dAcctBal  = (mAcctData['D_AcctBal'] as num).toDouble();
```

I don't know why Dart doesn't allow direct assignment of integer to double, but I'm sure there is a good reason.

Comment: A very good reason. Type annotations in Dart are optional, and they are treated as assertions (they are ignored in production mode). That means that a variable does not have a type, so assigning an integer to a variable declared as double must work the same whether the variable is declared double ("double x") or just dynamic ("var x"). This prevents any implicit conversion. In checked mode, the assignment is checked, and since 'int' is not a subtype of 'double', the type assertion fails. You have to do an explicit n.toDouble().

Comment: @lrn: Thanks for the explanation. I "should" study that. It had me puzzled, but I guess there are a few factors involved. While I have moved on from this for now, I presume that my little "solution" is OK. (as num).toDouble() is not very onerous, however, from a practical viewpoint, it did appear strange to me that an int that is perfectly compatible in range to a double could not be directly assigned to a double. As relatively simple as this little problem is, there are a few factors involved (including JS I guess - perhaps indirectly).